# Why does stream sorted() have trouble inferring my type?

Tags: java, java-stream

I was reading [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) and tried counting some words in a text file and found I could not reverse sort similarly to how it showed in **listing 1** of the article.

I have some code that works though:

```
public class WordCounter {
    public static final PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        //The need to put "", in front of args in the next line is frustrating.
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("", args))) {
            lines.parallel()
              .map(l -> l.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z\\s]", "").split("\\s"))
              .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
              .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                      Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                // Sort Map<K,V> Entries by their Integer value descending
                .entrySet().parallelStream()
// MY QUESTION IS ABOUT THIS METHOD:
                  .sorted(
                    Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue, Comparator.reverseOrder()))
// --------------------------------- //
                  .forEachOrdered(e -> out.printf("%5d\t%s\n", e.getValue(), e.getKey()));
        }
        out.close();
    }
}
```

So the article would suggest that the line:

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue, Comparator.reverseOrder()))
```

could be written as:

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue).reversed())
```

For this though, the Java compiler complains that:

> Error:(46, 49) java: invalid method reference   non-static method
>   getValue() cannot be referenced from a static context

The two `comparing` method signatures have the exact same first parameter and static scope, yet the former works while the latter complains about `getValue` being non-static.

My original thought was to write it as either:

```
.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
```

Which compiles and runs but is not reversed. Or as:

```
.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue().reversed())
```

Which again doesn't compile, giving an error message of:

> Error:(48, 62) java: incompatible types: java.util.Comparator<java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.Object,V>> cannot be converted to java.util.Comparator<? super java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.String,java.lang.Long>>

Okay, so, that should be:

```
.sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
```

Which works.

I can't seem to see how to give a similar generic type specification to the `Map.Entry::getValue` form in my "could be written as" line though.

Comment: *"I can't seem to see how to give a similar generic type specification to the Map.Entry::getValue form though."* `Map.Entry<String,Long>::getValue` Unfortunately, type inference still has limitations.

Comment: @Radiodef Thanks; So my IDE (IDEA CE 15) would highlight `getValue` here as red and complain that this reference to a method was not found. HOWEVER it compiles and runs correctly, implying that the internal Java compilation or syntax checker used by the IDEA is not agreeing with actual Java.

Comment: That's probably an IntelliJ bug then. I also have no idea why it gives you a "static context" error message in the one case.

Comment: @Radiodef I'd be happy to accept your answer if you fill out as such. It does answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to why this happens: while type inference has come leaps and bounds in Java 8, it will still only use the return target type if the return value is assigned to something.

In Java 7 we were only able to use this in an *assignment context* (using `=`) and it was a little bit clunky. In Java 8, it's less clunky and we can use it in *invocation contexts* (passed as a method argument, which assigns it to the formal parameter).

So the way I understand it, if the method invocation isn't used in an assignment context or invocation context, target type inference simply turns off, because it's no longer something called a *poly expression* ([15.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12), [18.5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.2)). So says the JLS.

In short, target type inference only works if the return value is:

- assigned directly to a variable using `=`, as in `v = foo();`.
- passed directly to a method, as in `bar(foo())`.

Once you chain a method call in, like `v = foo().zap()`, it stops working.

---

Lifted from my comment:

> I can't seem to see how to give a similar generic type specification to the `Map.Entry::getValue` form though.

This would be `Map.Entry<String, Long>::getValue`.